# How to restrict malicious and junk file upload in Java?

Tags: java

Hey Everyone I am using angular 5 and Java 8 for my application. While uploading a file fro front end i want to restrict malicious or junk file upload into my database using Java. Please help me with.

Comment: Everyone wants to restrict malicious or junk files being uploaded.  Do you mind telling us what type of files?  Text, image, porn?

Comment: Text Image Pdf PPT XLS GIF.

Comment: Each of those file types has a specific format that can be checked for malicious intent.  As far as junk, nothing replaces human inspection.

Comment: Will you please help with one of the format at least i can get some information about rest.

Comment: Found this with a Google search "GIF format".  The current format is GIF89a.  https://www.fileformat.info/format/gif/egff.htm

Answer (score 3):

*Short of not accepting uploaded files, there is no sure way of doing this.*

OK, now having said that, :), sure it is practically needed to accept uploaded files. In this case, 2 primary things that need to be focused on:

1. Keep the server safe from compromise
2. Keep the user using the application safe from compromise

To keep the server insulated from compromise, as far as possible (through design) don't accept file uploads that will be internally used by the server e.g. data in CSV format, XML configurations .... instead try to provide an UI to take the data (of course CSV data cannot be taken from UI)

If you have to take uploaded files and do not need to use it on server, Base64 (or other encoding) and keep it on;y to decode and serve up. This ofcourse does not prevent the user from getting compromised through maliciously engineered files.

For this, first you need to know what type of file it is, use content detectors e.g. [like Apache Tika](https://tika.apache.org/). However, first you need to limit your attack surface by accepting only certain type of files (try to limit it to the smallest set as possible). Once you receive a file try to detect its content. By practice, if the content cannot be detected, the file should be rejected.

Once the content is detected, the further analysis and countermeasures are dependent on the format (different formats have different vulnerabilities associated with the popular applications they are accessed with), a case in point is [CSV Injection](https://owasp.org/www-community/attacks/CSV_Injection).

As last point, the above does take very considerable investment in the implementation, update and maintenance of the mechanism, security is not free.

Do make a cost benefit analysis of the loss due to compromise versus the cost of the security mechanism.

As a general principal, appropriate level of security needs to be used for appropriate asset value.